# postgres lag when data is missing

Tags: postgresql

I have data on baseball players annual salaries, with some years missing. What I would like to do is calculate the min, max, average change in salary from the prior year for all players in a year.

For example data looks like below from the table 'salaries':

```
| playerid | yearid | salary |
| a        | 2016   | 10000  |
| b        | 2016   | 5000   |
| a        | 2015   | 9000   |
| b        | 2015   | 3000   |
| a        | 2014   | 3000   |
| b        | 2014   | 15000  |
| a        | 2010   | 1000   |
```

As you can see, player A has a yearly change of 1k and 6k. player B has a yearly change of 2k and -12k. So I would like a select statement that brings out:

```
| yearid | min change | max change | avg change |
|  2016  | 1k         |  2k        |     1.5k   |
|  2015  | -12k       |  6k        |     -9k    |
```

Is there a way to do this?

My lag function has unfortunately captured the difference between 2014 and 2010 for playerid a and that is obviously wrong. I couldn't figure out how to use the lag function only if the previous row's yearid was 1 less than the current rows yearid.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the previous year for the filtering:

```
select year, min(salary - prev_salary), max(salary - prev_salary),
       avg(salary - prev_salary)
from (select s.*,
             lag(s.salary) over (partition by s.playerid order by yearid) as prev_salary,
             lag(s.yearid) over (partition by s.playerid order by yearid) as prev_yearid
      from salaries s
     ) s
where prev_yearid = yearid - 1;
```

Or, you can just use a `join`:

```
select s.yearid, . . .
from salaries s join
     salaries sp
     on sp.playerid = s.playerid and sp.yearid = s.yearid - 1
group by s.yearid;
```

Comment: Has anyone compared the performance of `lag` vs `join` with higher volumes? In this case I would guess that the join is more efficient as `lag` here is looking up values, only to filter them out.

Comment: Is it possible to use something like `lag(s.salary) over (order by yearid rows '1 year' preceding)`? (I appreciate this doesn't work, but I mean specify the time difference instead of using the `offset` parameter of `lag`.)